# Parsing string containing Special Folder

Tags: c#, .net, directory, special-folders

I've allowed for custom paths to be entered and wanted the default to be something along the lines of:
`%UserProfile%/Documents/foo`, of course this needs to successfully parse the string and though it will work in Windows Explorer, I was wondering if I'm missing a library call or option for parsing this correctly.

DirectoryInfo's constructor certainly doesn't work, treating `%UserProfile%` like any other folder name.
If there is no good way, I'll manually parse it to substitute `%foo%` with the actual special folder location if it is in the Special Folders Enumeration.

Edit:
Code that does what I'm looking for (though would prefer a proper .NET library call):

```cs
var path = @"%UserProfile%/Documents/foo";
var specialFolders = Regex.Matches(path, "%(?<possibleSpecial>.+)%");
foreach (var spec in specialFolders.AsEnumerable())
{
    if (Enum.TryParse<Environment.SpecialFolder>(spec.Groups["possibleSpecial"].Value, out var sf))
    {
        path = Regex.Replace(path, spec.Value, Environment.GetFolderPath(sf));
    }
 }
```

Comment: `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),"Documents","foo")`.
I'm not sure what you asking exactly but this code give you the path

Comment: Only works for a specific, guaranteed special folder. Looking to parse folder paths containing special Folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) on the path before using it.

```
var pathWithEnv = @"%UserProfile%/Documents/foo";
var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathWithEnv);
// your code...
```